# LPUART1 not working on STM32L476 (based on VisualGDB)

Tags: stm32, mbed, nucleo, visualgdb

Hi I am developed a board based on the Discovery L476 board (STM32L476VGT6) using MBED and after porting it to VisualGDB everything works great. The only thing that doesn't work is LPUART1. I hooked it to PB10(LPUART1_RX), PB11(LPUART1_TX) but whenever I declare the port in my code and download it, the program hangs and doesn't even start:

```
Serial RS232(PB_11, PB_10);
```

If I remove this line, the code works great (but I can't use this port)

I changed the pin definitions in PeripheralPins.c so PB10 and PB11 will function as the LPUART TX and RX pins: (I added the lines)

```
const PinMap PinMap_UART_RX[] = { {PB_10, LPUART_1, STM_PIN_DATA(STM_MODE_AF_PP, GPIO_PULLUP, GPIO_AF8_LPUART1)},

//

const PinMap PinMap_UART_TX[] = { {PB_11, LPUART_1, STM_PIN_DATA(STM_MODE_AF_PP, GPIO_PULLUP, GPIO_AF8_LPUART1)},
```

but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/5389, the baud rate needs to be set at `[sys_clk / 4096 ... sys_clk / 3]`. Sys clock on this device is running at 80MHz. You could fix it in the HAL for this board until a real fix is deployed.